# Staying DRY with Async Calls in React Redux Application With Redux Thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

### Issue

I am currently experiencing a problem with how I want to perform an AJAX request that can be triggered by several
different UI elements on a page. The AJAX request always goes to the same endpoint, and always sends the same properties
from the redux store to the endpoint(although the properties values might change due to user interaction).

I am fully aware that my current implementation is terrible.

### Rundown

To paint a clearer picture, I am building a search page where several UI elements can trigger a new search being activated.
There is one endpoint, lets call it, "/api/search/", that expects a query string with data extracted from the Redux Store. It would look something like this:

```
term=some%20string&categories=243,2968,292&tags=11,25,99&articleType=All
```

Where I am getting tripped up is when a UI element needs to trigger a synchronous update to the store, but also needs to trigger a Thunk that performs the search. Here is my top level component where I pass down the "executeSearch" Thunk function to all child components that need to trigger a search. My initial thought here was that I could use one thunk to handle all of the interactions that require a search to be performed, instead of writing a separate thunk for each one.

P.S. DONT OVER ANALYZE THE CODE BELOW IF IT DOES NOT MAKE SENSE TO YOU. If you skim through the following section, then read the section "Three Scenarios", this might help give you a better understanding how everything works. Pictures are included in that section as well.

```
class App extends Component {
  executeSearch = () => {
    this.props.executeSearch(this.props.store); // This is my Thunk
  };

  render() {
    const { updateSearchTerm, clearAll, dropdownActive, dropdownType } = this.props;

    return (
      <section className="standard-content">
        <div className="inner-container narrow">
          <div className="centered">
            <h1>Search</h1>
            <h2 className="alt">Search our extensive database of research articles.</h2>
          </div>

          <SearchTerm initSearch={this.executeSearch} updateSearchTerm={updateSearchTerm} />
          <ExtraOptions clearAll={clearAll} />
          <Filters executeSearch={this.executeSearch} />
        </div>

        {dropdownActive ? (
          dropdownType === 'categories' ? (
            <CategoryDropdown executeSearch={this.executeSearch} />
          ) : (
            <TagDropdown executeSearch={this.executeSearch} />
          )
        ) : null}

        <SearchResults />
      </section>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    store: state,
    dropdownActive: state.dropdownActive,
    dropdownType: state.dropdownType
  };
};
```

The executeSearch function takes in all the values from the store, but only uses the ones I outlined at the beginning of this issue. There is a code sample of the entire redux store at the bottom of this post if it helps. Regardless, here is what the Thunk looks like:

```
export const executeSearch = criteria => {
  const searchQueryUrl = craftSearchQueryUrl(criteria);

  // if (term === '' && !selectedCategories && !selectedTags && articleType === 'All') {
  //   return { type: ABORT_SEARCH };
  // }

  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS });

    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`${window.siteUrl}api/search`, searchQueryUrl);
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS_SUCCESS, searchResults: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS_FAILED });
    }
  };
};

// Helper function to craft a proper search query string
const craftSearchQueryUrl = criteria => {
  const { term, articleType, selectedCategories, selectedTags } = criteria;
  let categoriesString = selectedCategories.join(',');
  let tagsString = selectedTags.join(',');

  return `term=${term}&articleType=${articleType}&categories=${categoriesString}&tags=${tagsString}&offset=${offset}`;
};
```

Keep in mind that the "criteria" argument here is the whole store object that I passed as a parameter inside of App.js. You will see that I only use the properties I need inside of the craftSearchQueryUrl function.

### Three Scenarios

I have included a screenshot(labeled with letters) where I hope to explain where things work, and where things don't.

[image]

A.) A user should be able to fill in this text field and when they press the magnifying glass, it should trigger the Thunk. This works fine because the value in the text field is updated in the store on every keystroke, which means the value in the store is always up to date before the user even has the chance to press the magnifying glass.

B.) By default the "All" checkbox is selected on initial page load. If a user clicks one of the other checkboxes listed beside it, it should immediately result in a search being initiated. This is where my issues start occurring. This is what I currently have for code on this one:

```
export default ({ handleCheckboxChange, articleType, executeSearch }) => (
  <div style={{ marginTop: '15px', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
    <span className="search-title">Type: </span>

    {articleTypes.map(type => (
      <Checkbox
        key={type}
        type={type}
        handleCheckboxChange={() => {
          handleCheckboxChange('articleType', { type });
          executeSearch();
        }}
        isChecked={type === articleType}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

When the checkbox changes, it updates the articleType value in the store(via handleCheckboxChange) and then says to execute the search function passed down from App.js. However, the updated articleValue type is not the updated one, as I believe the search function is called before the store has a chance to update this value.

C.) The same problem from B occurs here as well. When you click one of the buttons(Category or Tag) in the "Refine by" section, this dropdown appears with multiple checkboxes that can be selected. I actually store which checkboxes become checked/unchecked in local state until the user clicks the save button. Once the save button is pressed, the newly checked/unchecked checkbox values should be updated in the store and then a new search should be initiated via the Thunk passed down from App.js.

```
export default ({ children, toggleDropdown, handleCheckboxChange, refineBy, executeSearch }) => {
  const handleSave = () => {
    handleCheckboxChange(refineBy.classification, refineBy);
    toggleDropdown('close');
    executeSearch(); // None of the checkbox values that were changed are reflected when the search executes
  };

  return (
    <div className="faux-dropdown">
      <button className="close-dropdown" onClick={() => toggleDropdown('close')}>
        <span>X</span>
      </button>
      <div className="checks">
        <div className="row">{children}</div>
      </div>

      <div className="filter-selection">
        <button className="refine-save" onClick={handleSave}>
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It is important to note that the values used when executing the search are not the updated ones for B and C, but they are in fact updated properly inside the store.

### Other Solutions

My other idea was to maybe create a redux middleware, but honestly I could really use some expert help on this before trying anything else. The accepted solution would ideally be thorough in its explanation,
and include a solution that takes best architectural practices into mind when dealing with Redux applications. Perhaps I am just doing something fundamentally wrong here.

### Misc

Here is what my full store(in its initial state) looks like if it helps:

```
const initialState = {
  term: '',
  articleType: 'All',
  totalJournalArticles: 0,
  categories: [],
  selectedCategories: [],
  tags: [],
  selectedTags: [],
  searchResults: [],
  offset: 0,
  dropdownActive: false,
  dropdownType: '',
  isFetching: false
};
```

Comment: this should be an open bounty question

Comment: It gives people more incentive to answer the question because I have to give away some of my reputation points to them if they answer it correctly.

Comment: I had hard time embracing the problem right away, too. I assume it requires a fair amount of time investment. Yes, it's possible that you won't get a suitable answer initially. As for redux thunk, it's efficent mostly for simple scenarios. It's very likely that custom middleware may work better. Consider checking existing ones like Redux Saga or Redux Logic.

Comment: We'll see. Maybe someone can figure it out. If need be, I can absolutely clarify, and update the answer if something is not clear. I actually think its not that difficult of a question for someone with a lot of experience in this area. Perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: @estus that's what i faced too

Comment: Any chance you guys can upvote the question so hopefully people might see it? I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following block in `App` is the crux of the problem:

```
  executeSearch = () => {
    this.props.executeSearch(this.props.store); // This is my Thunk
  };
```

This `executeSearch` method has baked into it the `store` at the point of rendering `App`.

When you then do:

```
  handleCheckboxChange('articleType', { type });
  executeSearch();
```

by the time you get to `executeSearch` your Redux store will have been synchronously updated, but that results in a new `store` object which will cause `App` to be re-rendered but that **won't** affect the `store` object that `executeSearch` is using.

As others have indicated in the comments, I think the most straightforward way to deal with this is to use middleware that provides a mechanism to execute a side effect in response to redux actions after the store has been updated. I personally would recommend Redux Saga for this purpose, but I know there are other options. In this scenario you would have a saga that watches for any of the actions that should trigger a search and then the saga is the only thing that calls `executeSearch` and the saga will be able to pass the updated `store` to `executeSearch`.

Comment: You are right. Redux Saga is the way to go. I have been using it in a React Native app a little bit already, and probably should have went with it. Thank you.

Comment: I have posted an additional update of what I did to get it working as an answer. I won't be changing the selected answer, but hopefully this might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Going with Ryan Cogswell solution worked out magnificently. I was able to remove all of the code that made things confusing, and no longer need to worry about passing some of the state from the store to my async action creator since I am now using Redux Saga.

My refactored App.js now looks like:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      updateSearchTerm,
      clearAll,
      dropdownActive,
      dropdownType,
      fetchSearchResults
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <section className="standard-content">
        <div className="inner-container narrow">
          <div className="centered">
            <h1>Search</h1>
            <h2 className="alt">Search our extensive database of research articles.</h2>
          </div>

          <SearchTerm fetchSearchResults={fetchSearchResults} updateSearchTerm={updateSearchTerm} />
          <ExtraOptions clearAll={clearAll} />
          <Filters />
        </div>

        {dropdownActive ? (
          dropdownType === 'categories' ? (
            <CategoryDropdown />
          ) : (
            <TagDropdown />
          )
        ) : null}

        <SearchResults />
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

All I need to do is import the fetchSearchResults action creator into any redux connected component I need, and just make sure it gets executed. For example:

```
export default ({ handleCheckboxChange, articleType, fetchSearchResults }) => (
  <div style={{ marginTop: '15px', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
    <span className="search-title">Type: </span>

    {articleTypes.map(type => (
      <Checkbox
        key={type}
        type={type}
        handleCheckboxChange={() => {
          handleCheckboxChange('articleType', { type });
          fetchSearchResults();
        }}
        isChecked={type === articleType}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Here is what the action creator looks like now...

```
export const fetchSearchResults = () => ({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS });
```

This keeps your action creators pure and super simple to reason about. Whenever this action is dispatch in any part of my UI, my saga picks this up, and executes a search WITH the latest up to date version of the store.

Here is the saga that makes it work:

```
import { select, takeLatest, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { getSearchCriteria } from '../selectors';
import { Api, craftSearchQueryUrl } from '../utils';
import {
  FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS,
  FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS_FAILED
} from '../actions';

function* fetchSearchResults() {
  const criteria = yield select(getSearchCriteria);

  try {
    const { data } = yield call(Api.get, craftSearchQueryUrl(criteria));
    yield put({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS_SUCCESS, searchResults: data });
  } catch (err) {
    yield put({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS_FAILED, error: err });
  }
}

export default function* searchResults() {
  yield takeLatest(FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS, fetchSearchResults);
}
```